# Getting Return Value from Dynamic SQL Upsert Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a lot of tables with the same general schema of (Something)ID tinyint, (Something)Name varchar(50) like this:

```
            PhoneType
    ---------------------------
    PhoneTypeID | PhoneTypeName
    ---------------------------
          1     |  Cell Phone
          2     |  Landline
```

I've written a dynamic sql script that can do upserts on these tables, given the ID (update if not 0, insert otherwise), name value, and table name:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpsertListItemValue] 
            @ItemID varchar(4),
            @ItemName varchar(50),
            @TableName varchar(50)
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500)

SET @sql = 'IF ' + @ItemID + ' <> 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE ' + @TableName + '
       SET ' + @TableName + 'Name = ''' + @ItemName + '''
    WHERE ' + @TableName + 'ID = ' + @ItemID + '
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + '
       (' + @TableName + 'Name)
     VALUES
       (''' + @ItemName + ''')
END'
EXECUTE (@sql)
GO
```

I would like to have the ID of the item that was inserted/updated, and use that as the return value for my stored procedure. How do I do that?

For example, if I do

```
    EXEC UpsertListItemValue 1, 'Celluar Phone', PhoneType
```

I'd like to get `1` back (after update), and if I do

```
    EXEC UpsertListItemValue 0, 'Work Phone', PhoneType
```

I'd like to get `3` back (after insert).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SCOPE_IDENTITY in dynamic-sql script, because it returns values in the same scope.

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpsertListItemValue] 
            @ItemID varchar(4),
            @ItemName varchar(50),
            @TableName varchar(50)
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500)
      , @ret tinyint

SET @sql = 'IF ' + @ItemID + ' <> 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE ' + @TableName + '
       SET ' + @TableName + 'Name = ''' + @ItemName + '''
    WHERE ' + @TableName + 'ID = ' + @ItemID + '
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + '
       (' + @TableName + 'Name)
     VALUES
       (''' + @ItemName + ''')
END

SET @ret = isnull(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), ''' + @ItemID + ''')'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @sql, N'@ret tinyint OUTPUT', @ret = @ret output

RETURN @ret
GO
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms190315.aspx) to obain the identity value inserted

Comment: I've tried adding `RETURN @ItemID` and `RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to their respective blocks, but I get an error saying "A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context."